# Qiskit plot_histogram and count not working

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm trying to plot a histogram of my code but when I run

```
plot_histogram(results.get_counts(circuit))
```

it gives me a traceback error.

This is what I had before calling the histogram function:

```
-result = execute(circuit, backend = simulator).result()
```

and thereafter when I try to plot it by typing

```
-plot_histogram(results.get_counts(circuit))
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! Do you have a minimal (not-)working example? It can be hard to tell where the error is without more code (unless it's a case of typing `results.` when your variable is called `result`, in which case you should be typing `plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code without the example it looks like you missed an "s" on the result variable. `plot_histogram(results.get_counts(circuit))` should work.